# Is RTSP allowed on iOS or one MUST use Http Live Streaming instead?

Tags: ios, rtsp, http-live-streaming

Apple Http Live Streaming Overview document clearly states that streaming videos exceeding 10 minutes cannot be downloaded progressively and MUST be transferred using Http Live Streaming(HLS). It also states that the latency of HLS is in the neighbourhood of 30 seconds.

In my case, I am building an app that needs to receives live steaming videos in almost real-time. So on one hand I must use HLS for real time streaming but it is not fast enough. On the other hand I can not use anything else because it seems anything other than HLS is not allowed. I know RTSP is possible on iOS but will it be approved by the App Store?

Cheers,
M.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple is not transparent. The only way to know if an app will be rejected or accepted is to submit it.